# How to combine 'LIKE' and 'AND' Operator in SQL Statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How to combine 'LIKE' and 'AND' operator in query in ORACLE.

Suppose for example that I have the TEST table as shown below:

```
------------------------------------
col1    |   Col2
------------------------------------
A       |   RED
B       |   RED,BLUE
C       |   BLUE,GREEN
D       |   YELLOW,RED
------------------------------------
```

Now, if i am writing query as shown below that will return all records where either of them exists i.e. 'A,B,C,D'.

[Since here 'OR' operator is involved in REGEXP_LIKE]

```
SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(COL2,'ED|UE');
```

But I want `AND` operator to be used with `LIKE`. So it should return only `C` where both of them should exist.

How to write query for the same ?

Comment: Wild Guess (because I have never used oracle) but something like: SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(COL2,'ED') And REGEXP_LIKE(COL2,'UE');  Im guessing you could also get rid of the RegEx and Just use like

Comment: **C** would not match `ED|UE`. Are you mistaken or what is your requirement ?

Comment: @Ranhiru -- C does match `ED|UE`, because it matches `UE`.  It would not match both `ED` and `UE` which is what the OP implies.  Presumably it is record B that he is really after.

Comment: A better solution is to normalize your datamodel: put all colour items into separate rows.

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE Col2 LIKE '%ED%'
  AND Col2 LIKE '%UE%'
```